# Values being redrawn to screen when using depth buffer

Tags: c++, sdl

I have implemented a depth buffer using a `std::vector` with size 640 * 480. I can write and read from the buffer fine, but I have noticed the buffer appears to be copied along the left and right edges. The buffer is written row by row, going left to right and then going down one row.

I am quite certain the issue is related to the depth buffer, as disabling read from the buffer fixes the artifacts and shows the buffer is still being written properly.

I am using SDL as the graphics library, but not OpenGL.

[image: The mirrored depth buffer]

This buffer should only show one trapezium down the middle. The extra bits on the left and right should not appear.

What is happening to cause these artifacts? Alternatively, could I know some methods to debug this better.

Minimum code to replicate (as far as I can tell):

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct vec3d {
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float z = 0;
};

struct tri3d {
    vec3d p1;
    vec3d p2;
    vec3d p3;
};

struct vector2d {
    float x;
    float y;
};

float vect_dot_vect(vector2d a, vector2d b) {
    return(a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y);
}

int draw_tri(SDL_Renderer* renderer, std::vector<float>& buffer_out, tri3d triangle, int half_x_width, int half_y_width, int depth_test) { // depthmap is a linear array. Buffer out is pointing to the first value
    tri3d scaled_tri = triangle;

    // Find bounding box of tri
    int x = (int)std::min(std::min(floor(scaled_tri.p1.x), floor(scaled_tri.p2.x)), floor(scaled_tri.p3.x));
    int y = (int)std::min(std::min(floor(scaled_tri.p1.y), floor(scaled_tri.p2.y)), floor(scaled_tri.p3.y));
    int wx = (int)std::max(std::max(ceil(scaled_tri.p1.x), ceil(scaled_tri.p2.x)), ceil(scaled_tri.p3.x)) - x;
    int wy = (int)std::max(std::max(ceil(scaled_tri.p1.y), ceil(scaled_tri.p2.y)), ceil(scaled_tri.p3.y)) - y;

    // Find edge vectors
    vector2d ac;
    ac.x = scaled_tri.p3.x - scaled_tri.p1.x;
    ac.y = scaled_tri.p3.y - scaled_tri.p1.y;
    vector2d ab;
    ab.x = scaled_tri.p2.x - scaled_tri.p1.x;
    ab.y = scaled_tri.p2.y - scaled_tri.p1.y;

    float cc = vect_dot_vect(ac, ac);
    float cb = vect_dot_vect(ac, ab);
    float cp;
    float bb = vect_dot_vect(ab, ab);
    float bp;
    float invDenom = 1 / (cc * bb - pow(cb, 2));
    float u;
    float v;
    float w;

    float x_dif = x - scaled_tri.p1.x;
    float y_dif = y - scaled_tri.p1.y;

    int full_y_width = half_y_width * 2;
    float twoarea = (ab.x * ac.y - ab.y * ac.x);
    float barycentric_depth_weights[3] = { scaled_tri.p1.z, scaled_tri.p2.z, scaled_tri.p3.z };

    float depth_map_value;

    for (size_t i = wy; i != 0; i--) {
        for (size_t q = wx; q != 0; q--) {
            vector2d ap;
            ap.x = q + x_dif;
            ap.y = i + y_dif;
            cp = vect_dot_vect(ac, ap);
            bp = vect_dot_vect(ab, ap);

            // Find barycentric coords
            u = (bb * cp - cb * bp) * invDenom;
            v = (cc * bp - cb * cp) * invDenom;
            w = abs(1 - u - v);
            depth_map_value = (w * barycentric_depth_weights[0] + v * barycentric_depth_weights[1] + u * barycentric_depth_weights[2]);

            // Test if in tri
            if (u >= 0 && v >= 0 && u + v < 1) {

                // Test depth buffer
                if (buffer_out[(y + i) * full_y_width + x + q] < (0.0625 + depth_map_value)) {
                    buffer_out[(y + i) * full_y_width + x + q] = depth_map_value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

SDL_Window* win_make_window(int display_width, int display_height, SDL_WindowFlags flags) {
    // Returns an SDL window given screen size and flags
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Minimum code", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, display_width, display_height, flags);
    if (window == NULL) {
        printf("Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    return window;
}

int draw_buffer(SDL_Renderer* renderer, std::vector<float>& buffer, int half_screen_x, int half_screen_y) {
    // Iterate over every pixel and draw
    int depth_map_value;
    int screen_y = 2 * half_screen_y;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < screen_y; i++) {
        for (size_t q = 0; q < half_screen_x * 2; q++) {
            depth_map_value = buffer.at(screen_y * i + q) * 100;
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, depth_map_value, depth_map_value, depth_map_value, 255);
            SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, (int)q, (int)i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    const int half_screen_size[2] = { 320, 240 };   // Half size of screen. Needed it elsewhere
    const SDL_WindowFlags flags = SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN;

    // SDL startup boilerplate
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;

    // The tris, already projected
    tri3d tri1;
    tri1.p1 = { 577.173828, 453.201538, 1.37657264 };
    tri1.p2 = { 108.381744, 399.609772, 1.03054810 };
    tri1.p3 = { 547.989380,70.1635742,1.20407486 };

    tri3d tri2;
    tri2.p1 = { 108.381744, 399.609772, 1.03054810 };
    tri2.p2 = { 131.230850, 108.719635, 0.930727124 };
    tri2.p3 = { 547.989380, 70.1635742, 1.20407486 };

    //Create depth buffer
    std::vector<float> depth_buffer = {0};
    depth_buffer.resize(4 * static_cast<__int64>(half_screen_size[0]) * static_cast<__int64>(half_screen_size[1]));

    // Catch startup errors
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError()); // Catch startup errors

    else {
        SDL_Event event_handle;
        window = win_make_window(half_screen_size[0] * 2, half_screen_size[1] * 2, flags);
        screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

        // Draw tris to screen. No pixels actually drawn for debug purposes, only modifies depth buffer
        draw_tri(renderer, depth_buffer, tri1, half_screen_size[0], half_screen_size[1], 1);
        draw_tri(renderer, depth_buffer, tri2, half_screen_size[0], half_screen_size[1], 1);

        // Draw the buffer to screen
        draw_buffer(renderer, depth_buffer, half_screen_size[0], half_screen_size[1]);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    // Close everything else
    std::cin.get();
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

This is a school project and as such, I am not allowed to use SDL provided features except to draw to screen and for handling windows.

I modified the code to draw the depth buffer as it was being calculated, and noticed that when drawing from left to right, columnwise, the leftmost artifact no longer renderers. By changing the range of the region rendered, it appears that writing to one spot on the depth buffer also writes to another. No idea what to make of this yet.
[image: Partial render of image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea what's the deal with "half" sizes as you seem to use full size everywhere, but your array indexing is wrong. When iterating rectangle with [width, height], correct indexing code is e.g.:

```
for(int y = 0; y != height; ++y) {
    for(int x = 0; x != width; ++x) {
        int pixel = pixel_array[y*width+x];       // not y*height!
    }
}
```

Correct that in both places you index your depth array:

in `draw_tri`, `buffer_out[(y + i) * full_y_width + x + q]` - should be `full_x_width`, which you don't have yet,

in `draw_buffer`, `depth_map_value = buffer.at(screen_y * i + q) * 100;` - should be `screen_x`.